# Javascript- swap multiple images

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid, swap

First off, I am just starting to learn javascript so your patience is appreciated.  I have a problem that I am trying to figure out.  I am looking for a way to be able to click an image, and then click the image I want to swap it with. To elaborate, I have 9 images labeled 0-9, and 9 blank images.  My goal is to be able to click a numbered image and swap it for one of the blank images. All I have come up with is this, but it absolutely does not work in the way I need.

```
function swap1() {
    element = document.getElementById('0')
    if (element.src.match("0.jpg")) {
        element.src = "blank.jpg";
        alert(this.id)
    } else {
        element.src = "0.jpg";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img id="img0" src="0.jpg" onclick="swap(this);">
<img id="img1" src="1.jpg" onclick="swap(this);">
<img id="img2" src="2.jpg" onclick="swap(this);">

<script>
function swap(d){
  if (!d.osrc) d.osrc=d.src; //save the original src file
  if (d.blanked){
    d.src=d.osrc;
    d.blanked=null;
  } else {
    d.blanked=true;
    d.src='blank.jpg';
  }

  //un-blank the "other guys"

  for (var i=0;i<3;i++){ //change the upper bound as you add more images
    var obj=document.getElementById('img'+i);
    if (obj==d) continue; //skip self
    obj.blanked=null;
    obj.src=obj.osrc;
  }

}
</script>
```

The above code demonstrates two important techniques: a. passing in self-reference to avoid tedious naming; b. storing state variables in the DOM object

Comment: This is definitely more towards how I need it to operate.  However I am still running into the issue of placing "0.jpg" where "blank.jpg" is. When I click 0, it turns blank, but then I need to place that "0" where I want to.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I see what you mean. You don't have to hard code the "0" and "1" in the code. The image "src" attribute contains these values already. When you first click on the image, the "osrc" attribute is null. It is a custom flag I set. So I store the current "src" value to "osrc". If you clicked on an image that has "3.jpg", then osrc will be "3.jpg". When you click on the image for a second time, the blank is replaced with your originally stored value, in this case "3.jpg".

Comment: Okay, I follow.  Is there a way to put the values of "osrc" into "blank.jpg", and automatically put the values of "blank.jpg" where I originally clicked? For example; click "1.jpg", then click on any of the 9 blanks, and make the "blank" I click into 1.jpg" ?

Comment: edited the answer to address your request. keep in mind that single instance swapping and self-induced swapping are different interaction models. when you asked the question you should have made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

`id` can't start with a number. Change it to a valid `id` like `image` or just get the reference to the element via `event.target`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/b7C3H/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Say your html like

```
<img id="myimage" onclick="swap1()" src="0.jpg">

function swap1() {
    element = document.getElementById('myimage');
    if (element.src.match("0.jpg")) {
        element.src = "blank.jpg";
    } else {
        element.src = "0.jpg";
    }
}
```